# Struggling with selenium framework related questions

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have learned selenium webdriver from my own and now preparing for the interviews . I have prepared for the basics questions and now looking for selenium framework related questions. Can someone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

As you have said that you have a basic knowledge of selenium you should learn the framework also because there is a difference in basic selenium and framework of the selenium you should go through on it also. If still, you want to direct work on the framework of selenium, I recommend you directly go to the Rohit Shetty academy site and get the practice link by there.